# Can you call a class and then a tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, tags

I'm currently working on a website and it has a very long list of product codes. I was wondering if you can call a class and then a tag like you do with CSS (.downloadsUL li{})  using javascript. I need to make all of the li to float left, but im not sure how.

```
<ul class="downloadsUL" id="downloadsULid">
<li>LSL550A019</li> 
<li>LSL550A0221</li> 
<li>LSL550A0151</li>
<li>LSL550B029</li>
<li>LSL550B032</li>
And the list goes on for about 100 more
</ul>
```

Thanks for your time and have a nice day.
~Hantoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
var lis = document.getElementById('downloadsULid').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i=0; i<lis.length; i++) lis[i].style.float="left";
```

If you don't need to be compatible with IE7, the first line can be rewritten as

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#downloadsULid li');
```

which should sound familiar to you as the argument is a CSS selector.